# Chrome not starting on Ubunut 20.04 over CLI

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

I installed chrome on Ubuntu 20.04 terminal in order to serve as a internal browser for image rendering. Somehow it failes to start:

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Installation:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

How can this be debuged?

Comment: Please retry with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` in the folder with deb-file. Then run Google Chrome using `google-chrome`. What is your desktop environment? Do you use X11 or Wayland?

Comment: There is no desktop env as this is a remote server. Chrome will serve as a rendering engine for images. I reinstalled but the problem remains.